# Trying to read a text file from my web server, getting a file not found error

Tags: android

I have the following code in an android app. When running the app on my mobile phone from android studio the app works correctly and reads the file from my website, however after generating a build and publishing on google play store and installing from google store I then get a file not found error when running the app. I have internet permission in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The file exists on the server and I can open the file with a web browser from my mobile.
I have tried with  `http://leevalleyboats.co.uk/textfiles/videos.txt` and   `http://www.leevalleyboats.co.uk/textfiles/videos.txt`.

```
public class getVideoList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    int i = 0;
    String TextFileURL = "http://leevalleyboats.co.uk/textfiles/videos.txt";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            url = new URL(TextFileURL);
            HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream is=con.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while((TextHolder2 = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                 TextHolder1 = TextHolder2;
                videos[i] = TextHolder2;
                i++;
            }
            is.close();
            bufferReader.close();

        } catch (IOException malformedURLException) {
            malformedURLException.printStackTrace();
            TextHolder1 = malformedURLException.toString();
           // TextHolder1= "File Not Found";

        }
        return null;
    }
```

```
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="co.uk.leevalleyboats.lvbc">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity android:name=".MoleVideoActivity"/>

        <activity android:name=".TestActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
            android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LocksVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DrivingVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ToadVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".OtterVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".OwlVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FoxVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BadgerVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name=".VideoListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".NotificationReceiver" />
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".WaitingActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".DayBoatDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SmallBoatActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".PassengerBoatActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".WaitingnumberActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".a4SeaterVideo" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name=".DirectionsVideo"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name=".RowVideo"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name=".PedVideo"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name=".RattyVideo" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name=".PortLeeVideo"  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name=".a7SeaterVideo"  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name=".a5SeaterVideo" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name=".LadyVideoActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name=".PrideVideoActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It would be better if you attach your code and stack trace with your error

Comment: Sorry thought the code was included. Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: Manifest added. Thsnks

Comment: You can go through docs here https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from android 9 clear text http traffic is not permitted so any device having latest android os will fail to communicate using http. so use https and update your url as:
String TextFileURL = "https://leevalleyboats.co.uk/textfiles/videos.txt";

I edited back my answer to the previous solution as you mentioned in comment that worked for you.

Comment: Hi. The logcat created in android studio doesn't give an exception as there is no error when running via android studio. It only gives a file not found IOException after installing from Google play.  Or is there a log created on the mobile. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jabroo. You may want to have your original answer back here as that was the fix. Changed http:// to https:// and now all working. Many thanks.